# How to handle slow http request in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, loops, events

I'm new in nodejs, and i'm interested on event loop.But i have a confused issue in it.

If one http request need handle by 10 seconds, if all other requests must waiting for the slow request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** Not, other requests will work in parallel. They will not wait for the response from the first request.

**Long answer**

1. Your code makes a new request.
2. Node.js adds a new callback to pending callbacks list. This callback will run after the response from the server will arrive.
3. Node.js processes next code or timers or callbacks or etc.
4. 10 seconds have been passed. Your code receives the answer and finishes processing.

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS, most of your asynchronous tasks (like http requests, db access, etc.) will use callbacks or promises. What that means is that the event loop is free to handle other tasks until the callback is invoked or the promise resolves.

You can read more about the event loop [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/) in the NodeJS documentation.

Answer (score 0):

the event loop can only be slowed in an http request, when ever you are doing a hudge sync operation or whenever you are trying to send a file to a client without using the stream api. Whenever you read a hudge file with `fs.readFile` it kind of pause everything until the entire file is read, but using the stream api sends the file in chunk. To avoid slowing down your server you should always read file with the stream api for example using `fs.createReadStream` instead of `fs.readFile` depending on the size of the file